# How to display data preview in accordion with headers disabled

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I need some advice.

Currently, I am displaying certain data in J-Query Accordion. The requirement was such that user has to complete current step to proceed. Hence, I have disable the headers of all next panel so that user can not proceed ahead but can navigate to previous panels if any and coded the accordion such that on certain action the current panel will collapse and next header will be active along with next panel opened.

Now there is a small change in requirement. I am suppose to add an image on the headers which on hovering or clicking  will show preview of what is in the content panels?

How can I achieve this?
Also, is it possible to get the preview using new image if the header is disabled?

Comment: Can you post an example of how the accordion currently works?

Comment: Currently there are 5 default panels. When Accordion loads, First panel will be active with headers of all other panels disabled so that user can not navigate to next panel. In each panel there is a check box, by checking which next panel will open up with it's header active. 
All the previous panel's header w.r.t current open panel, will be active so that user can navigate back and forth till current open panel.
Now I need to add **preview functionality** to all the panels irrespective of its active/enabled state.